# update xml file at runtime in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

How can I add new nodes/elements/properties to the existing xml file at runtime in flex.
I have a xml file which is used to display components in flex.
I want to add/edit component and their properties at runtime.

xml file sample:

```
<view id="productView" label="Products">
<panel id="chartPanel" type="CHART" ChartType="Pie2D" title="Productwise Sales"  x="215" y="80" width="425" height="240" showValues="0" >  
  < /panel> 
< /view>
```

To add new component I have created an object with all the properties and elements of components. How can I convert this object in xml format and update the existing xml file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "xml" are you referring to a flex .mxml component, or do you have your own custom markup language which is loaded at runtime, parsed, and used to render components?

Comment: Here "xml" is pure xml file. At runtime im parsing this xml file to render components. 
I want to add new compnents at runtime and update this xml file.

Comment: Basically i want to create Designer kind of thing, using which user can add/edit components and properties of view/dashboard. i am storing view structure in a xml file. i parsed that file at runtime and display view. Basically How to convert an object (having values,properties and sub-objects) to xml and add that xml to the existing xml file. so that next time when i parsed xml file i'll get that new component in my view/dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to do so.

If you wanna create objects which is dinamically created trought XML, you must wrap each component which you are planing to use.

If i were on such a problem to solve, i would probably create a proxy class, which primary target will be to produce objects out of the xml, and check if the objects ( represented by their name ) exists - just to apply the new properties.

you basically shall override each class which you are planing to use in order to be refreshed trought XML ( some Interface implementation would do the job here, due the common behaviour ).